# java regex pattern split commna

Tags: java, regex

```
String line = "a=1,b=\"1,2\",c=\"[d=1,e=1,11]\"";
String[] tokens = line.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)|,(?=\"[\\([^]]*\\)|[^\"]]*\")");
for (String t : tokens) {
System.out.println("> " + t);
}
System.out.println("-----------------------");
```

Console

```
> a=1
> b="1,2"
> c=[d=1
> e="1,1"]
-----------------------
```

I want to result

Console

```
> a=1
> b="1,2"
> c=[d=1,e="1,1"]
-----------------------
```

Help for java regex pattern to split comma(,)

Thanks

Comment: As per your requirement you have to write your own parser because regex is worked when there is any regular pattern follows. But in your case you want to split on the basis of , and after , there should be alphabet and this complination should not be a part of any breaces. So regex not help in this type of cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
String line = "a=1,b=\"1,2\",c=\"[d=1,e=1,11]\"";
String[] tokens = line.split(",(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)");
for (String t : tokens)
    System.out.println("> " + t);
```

**This regex matches a comma ONLY if it is followed by even number of double quotes.** Thus commas inside double quote aren't matched however however all outside commas are used for splitting your input.

PS: This will work for balanced quoted strings only .e.g. this won't work: `"a=1,b=\"1,2"` as double quote is unbalanced.

**OUTPUT:**

```
> a=1
> b="1,2"
> c="[d=1,e=1,11]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one `,(?=\\w=(\".+\"))`

Answer (score 0):

I tried your sample code in netbeans, I got this out put.

```
> a=1
> b="1,2"
> c="[d=1,e=1,11]"
```

Isnt this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I would program it:

```
public static void main( String argv[] ) {
        String line = "a=1,b=\"1,2\",c=\"[d=1,e=1,11]\"";

        boolean quote = false;
        String token = "";
        List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
        for( int i=0; i < line.length(); i++ ) {
            char c = line.charAt( i );

            switch( c ) {
                case ',':
                    if( quote ) {
                        token += c;
                    } else {
                        tokens.add( token );
                        token = "";
                    }
                    break;

                case '"':
                case '\'':
                    quote = !quote;
                    token += c;
                    break;

                default:
                    token += c;
                    break;
            }
        }
        tokens.add( token );

        System.out.println( tokens );
    }
```

output:

```
[a=1, b="1,2", c="[d=1,e=1,11]"]
```