# Extracting a string beween two strings

Tags: java, string, substr, substring

I have a String like this

```
String str = "www.google.com/..../upload/FileName.zip
```

I want to extract the string "FileName" from above string. I tried substr() method but couldn't found any solution.

Comment: Why did your attempt fail?

Comment: I think substr() method takes index. But I couldn't found how to use substr() to extracting a string present betwwen two different strings.

Comment: `String#lastIndexOf`  method is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it what you are looking for ?

```
  String lastPart= yourUrl.substring(yourUrl.lastIndexOf('/')+1, yourUrl.length());
  String fileName = lastPart.substring(0, lastPart.lastIndexOf('.'));
```

Considering the given format won't change.

[Demo](https://ideone.com/YNMnHb)

Comment: yeah, this format won't change.

Comment: Then it works and have a demo by clicking that link.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
    String str = "www.google.com/..../upload/FileName.zip";
    File file=new File(str);
    String fileName=file.getName();// now fileName=FileName.zip
    System.out.println(fileName.split("\\.")[0]);
```

Out put:

```
    FileName
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the part between the last slash and the dot:

```
String filename = str.replaceAll(".*?(?:/(\\w+)\\.\\w+$)?", "$1");
```

This regex has some special sauce added to return a blank if the target isn't found, by making the target optional and the leading expression reluctant.

Comment: Aren't anchors needed?

Comment: @Quincunx yeah thx - added end anchor $. Don't need start anchor.

Comment: This is exactly the method I was thinking of; I rather like regular expressions. This is clear. I can easily tell what it is doing. On the other hand, for some of these other answers, I find it less clear.

Comment: @quincunx I've added a bit of Kung Fu to the regex so it returns blank if a filename is not found. There's no way a non-regex approach with this behaviour could be done so succinctly.

Comment: And now I wish I could give 3 upvotes. I'd definitely call this the best answer, though if this is used in some shared situation, it would probably be better to use the regex form with comments, so noobs who don't know regex can understand what this does.

Comment: @Quincunx you can donate regex-fu rep by upvoting [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985909/regex-pattern-for-split/17986078#comment26296217_17986078) - I'm going to try to turn that low voted (but pretty good imho) answer into a [reversal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String str = "www.google.com/..../upload/FileName.zip";
    String  str1[] = str.split("/");
    String file=str1[str1.length-1];
    String fileName=file.substring(0, file.lastIndexOf("."));
    System.out.println(fileName);
```

Output

```
FileName
```