# Split Java String by space and not by double quotation (") that includes space

Tags: java, split

I want split a phrase on spaces, and not spaces within a quoted string (i.e., a string within pair of double quotation marks `"`).

For example:

```
software term "on the fly" and "synchrony"
```

Should be split into these 5 segments:

```
software  
term   
on the fly  
and  
synchrony
```

So how could I implement this in java?

Comment: You can't rewrite the rules of Java itself... Some languages are flexible enough to do that, but not Java.

Comment: I think the question is just how to write a function that will convert the string `"software term \"on the fly\" and \"synchron\""` to the list `["software", "term", "on the fly", "and", "synchron"]`.

Comment: Yes,this result is I expected.anyone knows how to implement this with Java API.

Comment: Note that the duplicate is the same basic problem, but the duplicate splits on comma and quotes on `[` and `]` - just replace the comma in that regex for a space, and replace the `\\[` with `\"`

Comment: @Bohemian It does not seem like so. Have you tested those changes you suggest?

Comment: In case this never gets reopened, here's my answer. https://gist.github.com/chris-martin/097f3bfd966c915ac0b0

Comment: @acdcjunior replace the comma, remove the `(?=([^\\[]*?\\[[^\\]]*\\][^\\[\\]]*?)*$)` part and you'll be fine. @ChrisMartin your suggestion [doesn't work with multiple spaces](http://ideone.com/ZRCXLs). And here's [my suggestion](http://ideone.com/2GlriL)

Comment: @acdcjunior Yes - I just realised the other difference: The duplicate is the same basic problem, but the duplicate splits on comma **and quotes using `[` and `]`** - just replace the comma in that regex for a space, **and replace `\\[` and `\\]` with `\"`**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex pattern for split](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985909/regex-pattern-for-split)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson already tried that as a dup, but wasn't clear to OP and others and there were several reopen requests. Also, that's a more complicated situation. I have posted a new solution as an answer here.

Answer (score 8):

This regex achieves the split for you, and cleans up any delimiting quotes:

```
String[] terms = input.split("\"?( |$)(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)\"?");
```

It works by splitting on a space, but only if it is followed by an *even* number of quotes.
The quotes themselves are consumed, so they don't end up in the output, by including them optionally in the split term.
The term `( |$)` was needed to capture the trailing quote.

Note that if the first term could be quoted, you'll need to clean up that leading quote first:

```
String[] terms = input.replaceAll("^\"", "").split("\"?( |$)(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)\"?");
```

---

Test code:

```
String input = "software term \"on the fly\" and \"synchron\"";
String[] terms = input.split("\"?( |$)(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)\"?");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(terms));
```

Output:

```
[software, term, on the fly, and, synchron]
```

Answer (score 1):

alternative to the previous post:

```
    boolean quoted = false;
    for(String q : str.split("\"")) {
        if(quoted)
            System.out.println(q.trim());
        else
            for(String s : q.split(" "))
                if(!s.trim().isEmpty())
                    System.out.println(s.trim());
        quoted = !quoted;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String str = "software term \"on the fly\" and \"synchron\"";
    String[] arr = str.split("\""); // split on quote first
    List<String> res = new LinkedList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i].trim();
        if ("".equals(arr[i])) {
            continue;
        }
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            String[] tmp = arr[i].split("\\s+"); // second, split on spaces (when needed)
            for (String t : tmp) {
                res.add(t);
            }
        } else {
            res.add("\"" + arr[i] + "\""); // return the quote back to place
        }

    }
    System.out.println(res.toString());
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[software, term, "on the fly", and, "synchron"]
```